# dial tcp [::1]:6397: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows, go, redis

I am writing a simple Go web application with Redis (trying out redis for the first time) on Windows. I'm using the go-redis package to connect to Redis.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var client *redis.Client
var tmpl *template.Template

func init() {
    client = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     "localhost:6397",
        Password: "",
        DB:       0,
    })
    tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("./templates/*.gohtml"))
    pong, err := client.Ping().Result()
    fmt.Println(pong, err)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler).Methods("GET")
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    comments, err := client.LRange("comments", 0, 10).Result()
    check(err)
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.gohtml", comments)
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, I get

> dial tcp [::1]:6397: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The only answer that I could find was to "start the redis server". My redis server is up and running (Checked it by using the "PING" command in redis client). I have also tried running it as administrator, but no luck.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot attached]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening most likely because of the Redis server is running on port `6379` (that is the default port for Redis server) but you are trying to connect to the port `6397`.

Change the Server Address to:

`Addr:     "localhost:6379"`

From
`Addr:     "localhost:6397"`

And that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it!

Really embarrassed though, considering how silly my problem was. Thanks again!

Comment: It happens, no problem.